# How to set the horizontal menu to be center without setting the specific width

Tags: asp.net, css

I am styling my horizontal menu in asp.net

```
<div id="menu" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" >
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="list">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text=""  Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="">
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value="" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value="" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text=""  Value="">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text=""  Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text=""  Value="">
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text=""  Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text=""  Value="">                             
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="" Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value=""></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" Value="" Target="_blank"></asp:MenuItem>

            </asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div><!-- #menu-->
```

My page width is 1200px. 
However sometime I have 5 menu lists, sometimes I have 4 menu lists depend on the user. 
I need to make a webpage that can always show the menu in the center.

Is anyone know how to set the horizontal menu to be center without setting the specific width with CSS?

Comment: Please show your actual HTML + CSS, not your .NET code.

Comment: with css `text-align:center` for id=menu div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#menu {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will make the inner element center horizontally and it works without setting a specific width. Works on IE8+ and modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

set the css of the div with id menu

```
margin:0 auto;
Display: inline-block;
```

This will place it to center of the browser

Answer (score 1):

set the css of the div with id menu

```
#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    Display: inline-block;
}
```

This will place it to center of the browser

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the css rule: `text-align`

Also another option would be use:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

The vertical align is to remove the extra margin at the bottom

It would work fine

Comment: Text-align will only work if the elements inside the menu are `inline-block` elements

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this same problem, and after trying all the answers I came across I stumbled on the following which worked for me when placed in the style tag/css for the Div:

**table-layout:fixed;**

Hope that helps.